# Add data if current day is equal to last day of the month ONCE every month

Tags: php, codeigniter, date

I want to update my data if the current date is equal to last day of the month leave variable will update +1 once every month only, but it seems that when I refresh the homepage it keeps on adding.

```
function get_leave() {
    $current_date = date('d'); // current date
    $lastDayOfMonth = date('t'); // last day of the month
    $leave = 1;
    $total_add_leave = 0;
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT total_leave,user_id FROM user');
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
        if($current_date == $lastDayOfMonth) { //if current day is equal to last day of the month ADD 1
            $total_add_leave = $row['total_leave'] + $leave;
        }
        $this->db->set('total_leave',$total_add_leave);
        $this->db->where('user_id', $row['user_id']);
        $this->db->update('user'); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course it does. You're updating the database **unconditionally** in your loop.

Comment: Add a updated_at column and check if last updated_at is current month then do not update the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as below:

```
    $current_date = date("y-m-d");
    $last_day_of_the_month = date("y-m-t", strtotime($current_date));

    if($current_date == $last_day_of_the_month) {
        $total_add_leave = $row['total_leave'] + 1;
        // database updating query must be placed in this condition
    }
```

Comment: it still adds every time i refresh the page sir.

Comment: is the get_leave() function called when the page refreshed?

Comment: I think your get_leave() function gets called when the page refreshed and when the function gets called it meets the condition, so it executes the query. if so then you may create a flag field inside the database when the leave updates once, so it won't update the field second time.

Answer (score 0):

With this function you will find last date of month "t gives you last date of month"

```
date("Y-m-t");
```

then compare with current date

```
if(date("Y-m-d") == date("Y-m-t"))
{
  // write your logic here
}
```